# Dropna drops all rows including numeric

Tags: python, pandas

When I try to  drop NaN values from this dataset, It results in  None
I cannot understand what is wrong with this. Is this something about dataset ?
I inspected the dataset, there are definitely rows that don't contain NaN values.
And of course it prints out if I don't do dropna.

https://www.kaggle.com/mczielinski/bitcoin-historical-data

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

df  = pd.read_csv('D:\BTC_price history.csv')
df['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'],unit='s') #converted to date utc

df = df.dropna(inplace = True)
print(df)
```

Comment: if you remove the line ```df['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'],unit='s')```, does still ```df``` is None after dropna? If it is working without that line, then this line cause the problem: you get NaN in all Timestamp column

Answer (score 1):

`df.dropna(inplace = True)` does not return anything, it drops in place

Do this:

```
df.dropna(inplace=True)
```

or

```
df = df.dropna()
```

Comment: but I have df = df.dropna(inplace=True) in code..

Comment: Read again. That won't work, you can't assign it back to df if you use `inplace=True`

Comment: oh sorry, I realized what I have done wrong. I had to use either of this, not both. Though I don't think my question wasn't closed relatively...

Comment: thank you, solved it

Comment: Ok cool, you can mark it as the answer